# Referencing variables in another Swift file

Tags: ios, swift

I have a project with a few different Swift files linked to equivalent View controllers, as well as a 'Data' Swfit file with variables for DB storage as well as methods for saving and retrieving data (via REALM) in an MVC type structure altogether.

So from the main project `iFindTableViewController`, I have called these methods which are in `iFindItems`by the following:

```
iFindItem().loadRealm(withFileName: String)
```

(for example)

So my question is this - is this acceptable practice, or should I create some form of reference to the other file first, instead of using the filename `iFindItem()` and initialising it there? Both methods seem to work OK.

EDIT:

More succinctly, is it better practice to do this :

```
let vc = MainViewController()
vc.text = "Some Text"
```

Or this :

```
MainViewController().text = "Some Text"
```

Comment: Your question is very confusing, you can't reference a file in swift only the types, structs, classes etc defined in a file. Are you perhaps thinking about access control, i.e public, private etc?

Comment: I have a mainViewController and a Swift file (as a basic example) and the swift file has methods in, that I need to call from the mainViewController.  I am currently calling these methods by 'referencing' Swift().SomeMethodName

Comment: Regarding your edit, I prefer the first version if I am going to use the variable several times. The main reason is that I can use a shorter name to make my core more readable, for me vc is probably to short though.

Comment: Hi, Joakim, thanks - yes I agree that vc is generally too short and it was for demo only.  I have used destinationVC before which isnt too bad.  As I say, I am getting my head around SWIFT and one thing you cannot always 'learn' so easily, is the 'correct' way to do things - as there are multiple ways of doing things.